# Interesting exercises using printf & scanf only

Tags: c

I'm running out of ideas for my "Beginning C" class, and the only topics I've discussed so far are Data types, Variables & the printf & scanf functions.

My last quizzes involved simple formulas (area of a circle, volume of a cube..) enclosed inside the printfs..

`eg. printf("volume = %d",length * width * height);`

I'm looking for something more interesting using only printfs and scanfs :(

Update~ Just to clarify: My students don't know how to use conditional statements and iterative statements yet. It's only week 2, and this is their very first programming class :'( And yes, they can only retrieve the input, then modify it in some way before they output it in the console. I can play with escape sequences (create a box asterisks) or format specifiers (a 3 precision division operation) but that's it..

Comment: In my view, time to swiftly move on to the more interesting material, like loops and conditions - before they die of boredom.

Comment: unfortunately, it's already prelim exams :( we were pushed back by 2 weeks worth of AH1N1 outbreak "vactions", so that's the only topics we've discussed till now :'( anyways, I'd really appreciate some help on the exercises..

Answer (score 2):

- Write a program that asks the user
  their name, age, and favorite letter
  of the alphabet.
- Print a single sentence containing
  all the information.
- Bonus: Print a sentence
  containing the first letter of their
  name.

### Answer:

```
char name[50];
int age;
char letter;

printf( "\nWhat is your name? " );
scanf( "%s", name );

printf( "\nHow old are you? " );
scanf( "%d", &age );

printf( "\nWhat is your favorite letter of the alphabet? " );
scanf( " %c", &letter ); //skipping whitespace

printf( "\n\n-------------------\n\n");
printf( "Your name is %s, you are %d years old, and your favorite letter of the alphabet is %c.\n", name, age, letter );

printf( "The first letter of your name is %c", name[0] );
```

If you'd like some math in there, ask them questions like:

- Write a program that asks the user
  how many weeks until christmas, then
  print out how many seconds there are
  until christmas (given the number of
  weeks entered only).

Answer (score 2):

I have used a unit converter previously.

- Convert temperatures to and from
  Celsius, Fahrenheit, and Kelvin.
- Change the base as mentioned by
  [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157129/interesting-problem-using-printf-scanf-only/1157147#1157147).
- Cooking weights and measures has lots of interesting conversions.

Answer (score 0):

How about a base-converter. In other words, prompt for a number in decimal and a number system (say, 2 for binary or 16 for hex) and then output the number in that system.

Comment: Can you do this without a conditional like 'if (base == 16) { format = "%x"; }' ?

Comment: I posted this before the update, I was thinking that conditionals would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Using **only** printfs and scanfs, and nothing more?  You can only retrieve input and output the input if that's the case.

I don't think that's what you meant though...

**Math/Algorithm Related**

- Generate/Output the first N prime numbers
- Calculate factorial(n) recursively/iteratively
- Use C as a tool to Find a formula for sum of alternating sums up to positive N

**Game Related**

- Write a simple character based pong game (single player)
- Write "nibbles" a.k.a "snake" (char based)

Comment: You will need conditional and loop statements for most of these. First time programming students will not know how to solve these type of problems.